# Different values for print or console print out

Tags: swift, xcode

I am curious about a behaviour I have just seen while developing a feature for an iOS app and I wonder if anyone knows the reason.

I have a `Codable` object that I want to encode

`let encoded = try encoder.encode(featureEnvelope)`

Just after this I have a print like the following and a breakpoint:
`print(String(data: encoded, encoding: .utf8)!)`

On the endpoint I do the following:
`po String(data: encoded, encoding: .utf8)!`

The results for both expressions are slightly different:
for the print:
`{"boost_share_link":{"enable":true}}`

and for the print out:
`"{\"boost_share_link\":{\"enable\":true}}"`

Why the console shows escaping characters? And which one is the *correct* one?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` is showing the value of the `String`.

`po` is showing the value as a `String` literal. Note the leading and trailing quotes. Since it is a string literal, certain characters (such as other quotes) need to be escaped.

Both are correct in their own way.

But the output of `print` is what you would generally think of as the *correct* one since the string doesn't actually contain `\` characters or the leading and trailing quotes.